# Problems implementing "toEnum" in Haskell

Tags: dictionary, haskell

haven't got implementation problems with fromEnum, keep running into them using toEnum. Tried different type sigs, but keep getting it all wrong.

```
decodeROT = map (-1) (map toEnum [74,33,105,57,33,117,112,70,111,118,110])
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The `(-1)` in your code should be the function "subtract one", but is actually interpreted as the "negative one" constant. Since "-1" is a number it is not a function, and errors will arise.

You can use `pred` for the predecessor function, or `subtract 1`, or the explicit `(\x -> x-1)`.

Also note that, after you have applied `toEnum`, the type is no longer necessarily numeric. `pred` will still work, but other alternatives may fail. You should decrement the numbers before applying `toEnum`.

Minor point: `map f (map g list)` is equivalent to `map (f . g) list`.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you want to convert `[74,33,105,57,33,117,112,70,111,118,110]` to String by translating it one position, so It becomes `"I h8 toEnum"` isn't it?

So:

- `map toEnum [74,33,105,57,33,117,112,70,111,118,110]` is type String, so when you apply `map (-1)` to it, you are actually trying to subtract a Int to a Char, and that is wrong!
- Secondly, `map (-1)` is a bad expression since haskell understand -1 as the actual number *minus one* rather than the substract function

Taking this to consider, your code should be:

```
decodeROT = map toEnum (map ((+) (-1)) [74,33,105,57,33,117,112,70,111,118,110])
```

Which can be written briefly as

```
decodeROT :: String
decodeROT = map (toEnum . (+) (-1)) [74,33,105,57,33,117,112,70,111,118,110])
```

Regards

Comment: Perfect explanation! Many thanks for that. This makes it totally clear to me. So: problem solved for me.

Comment: Nice!, Don't forget to mark question as answered ;)